# Whats the difference between *variablename and &variablename

Tags: objective-c, c, variables, pointers, ampersand

In Objective C, C and other pointer supported languages what is the difference between *variablename and & variablename. Isnt it that both contain address location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*variablename` points to the content of a Pointer considering 'variablename' is a pointer. Whereas `&variablename` points to the address of the variablename.

`&variablename` can be applied on normal variables as well as pointers, wheread `*variablename` can be applied only on pointers.

Comment: For example: If you want a pointer to point to a variable you can write: `pointerToVar = &var` and access the value of `var` using `*pointerToVar = 5`

Answer (score 5):

```
&variablename
```

Contains the address location of the pointer.

```
*variablename
```

Returns the value that is stored in that memory address.

Heres a picture to better understand
[image]

The pointer ourPointer holds the address of the integer variable. To get the value of that integer we use the * before the name of our pointer *ourPointer and it gives us the value stored in the address that it holds.

Answer (score 0):

int *a; //The variable a points to the address of an integer

int &a; //The variable a is an reference to another integer

refer [Reference Vs pointers](http://eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023307/References-vs-Pointers)